# I would like to know how an OpenGL driver will be implemented to learn opengl internals?

Tags: opengl, architecture, graphics, gpu

I'm learning OpenGL and really like to know how the interaction with the Graphics card will be.

I feel understanding how it was implemented in the Graphics driver, will let me know complete internals of the opengl(With this I can know what stages/factors influence my decisions regarding performance in opengl).

Are there any ways for this path to proceed.Does exploring the 'Mesa lib' will help me in this aspect? Am I in the right path?

[I posted this question in SOF but it seems here is the right place for this Question.]

Comment: I consider this off-topic. Stackoverflow is most likely the better place for this.

Comment: While OpenGL is used often in game development, this question only asks about programming and is not related to game dev. I think it should be migrated. It is still a good question though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start be reading this blog: http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/

Comment: Wow, very interesting

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mesa3D. It's an open source OpenGL implementation for GNU/Linux and many other OS's.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site has some great information about the subject: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pipeline.html